# Consuming parameter packs recursively in C++

Tags: c++

I want to come up with a Lisp-like cons list implementation in C++. I will give you my attempt first.

```
template <typename E1, typename E2>
struct pair {

    constexpr pair() :first{E1{}}, second{E2{}}, empty{true} 
    {}

    constexpr pair(E1 const &f, E2 const &s)
    :first{f}, second{s}, empty{false} 
    {}

    E1 first;
    E2 second;
    bool empty;
};

template <typename Head, typename Tail>
struct cons{
    constexpr cons() :_cons{pair<Head, Tail>{}}
    {}

    constexpr cons(Head h, Tail t) :_cons{pair<Head, Tail>{h, t}}
    {}

    template <typename... Args>
    constexpr cons(Args... args)
    {
        // I want cons(1, 2, 3) to expand into below call
        // in main and cons(1, 2, 3, 4) to expand into
        // cons{1, cons{2, cons{3, cons{4, cons<int, int>()}}}}
    }

    constexpr auto car() {
        return _cons.first;
    }

    constexpr auto cdr() {
        return _cons.second;
    }

    pair<Head, Tail> _cons;
};

int main(){
    constexpr cons c{1, cons{2, cons{3, cons<int, int>{}}}};
}
```

Basically, I want to fill in the part below that implements a variadic constructor.

```
template <typename... Args>
constexpr cons(Args... args)
{
    // I want cons(1, 2, 3) to expand into below call
    // in main and cons(1, 2, 3, 4) to expand into
    // cons{1, cons{2, cons{3, cons{4, cons<int, int>()}}}}
}
```

I don't know how can I process parameter packs in such a recursive way. If an `initializer_list` solution is better, I can look at that as well. In the end, I want to be able to do:

```
cons c1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

and it will become

```
cons{1, cons{2, cons{3, cons{4, cons<int, int>()}}}};
```

Here is my solution I came up with after asking the question, it is in the `make_list` function.

[My Solution](https://godbolt.org/g/zm6y6N)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not being familiar with Lisp, I went by your description as much as I could. You write helper functions `make_cons` and delegate the construction to the move constructor

```
template<typename, typename>
struct cons;

template<typename U>
auto make_cons(U u)
{
    return cons<U, cons<U, U>>{u, {}};
}

template<typename U, typename... Args>
auto make_cons(U u, Args... args)
{
    return cons<U, decltype(make_cons(args...))>{u, make_cons(args...)};
}

template<typename H, typename T>
struct cons
{
    constexpr cons() :_cons{pair<H, T>{}} {}
    constexpr cons(H h, T t) :_cons{pair<H, T>{h, t}} {}
    template<typename... Args>
    constexpr cons(Args... args) : cons(make_cons(args...)) {}

    pair<H, T> _cons;
};

template<typename U, typename... Args>
cons(U, Args...) -> cons<U, decltype(make_cons(std::declval<Args>()...))>;

template<typename U>
cons(U) -> cons<U, cons<U, U>>;
```

By your example, I'm assuming you want to have as the last term be `cons<U, U>` where `U` is the same type as the terms coming before. You use it as

```
auto c1 = make_cons(1, 2, 3, 4);
cons c2 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
print<decltype(c1)> p1;
print<decltype(c2)> p2;
```

[Live (read the error message to see the resulting type)](https://godbolt.org/g/68zweM)

Comment: Where is the move constructor here?

Comment: @meguli It's implicitly declared. It is used at `cons(make_cons(args...))`

Comment: I think there is a simpler solution, without use of `decltype`, instead of delegating to a constructor, you could make two versions of the function, one with only a pair, and the other is with varadic template. Where it will be resolved recursively till you reach the pair version.

Comment: Can you see my solution, I added a Compiler Explorer link to the question. Do we have anything different in terms of performance?

Comment: Btw, I don't know what is the use of a compile-time data structure like this. It isn't able to handle lists of even size say bigger than 100.

Comment: @meguli Templates weren't intended to be used as lists, compilers aren't optimized to handle large lists. It can handle small lists though.

Comment: The last term is not a `cons<U, U>`, it should be a special object that represents an empty list.

Comment: @bipll I don't really know Lisp, I only inferred from OP's examples. And from his own attempt, it seems like this is what's wanted.

Answer (score 2):

@PasserBy 's answer inspired me to do that:

```
////
template <typename Head, typename Tail>
struct cons{
    constexpr cons() :_cons{pair<Head, Tail>{}}
        {}

    constexpr cons(Head h, Tail t) :_cons{pair<Head, Tail>{h, t}}
        {}

    constexpr auto car() const {
        return _cons.first;
    }

    constexpr auto cdr() const {
        return _cons.second;
    }

    pair<Head, Tail> _cons;
};
////
template <typename Head, typename Tail>
constexpr cons<Head, Tail> makeCons(Head h, Tail t) {
    return cons<Head, Tail>(h, t);
}

template <typename Head, typename... Args>
constexpr auto makeCons(Head h, Args... args) {
    return makeCons(h, makeCons(args...));
}
////
```

The first part is exactly yours, but with removal of your varadic template constructor. Also made the getters const, to be able to be used in calling code (calling a constexpr with a non-const method is a compile-time error).

The second part is TWO template functions, the second is the varadic version, where it takes a head, and varadic template to recursively pass it to another version to itself,  the first is the specialization of the template function where it accepts only two arguments.

So the template function will keep resolving to itself (with decreasing one argument), till it is only two, where it will be resolved to the creation of a `cons` with a pair.

Then call it from your code like this:

```
constexpr auto c = makeCons(1, 2, 3, 4);
std::cout << c.car();
std::cout << c.cdr().car();
std::cout << c.cdr().cdr().car();
```

`makeCons(1, 2, 3, 4)` will recurively resolve to
`makeCons(1, makeCons(2, 3, 4))`, which will resolve to
`makeCons(1, makeCons(2, makeCons(3, 4)))`

`makeCons(3, 4)` is the specialized version

Comment: @PasserBy, if I may ask why this is better? I'm only human. :)

Comment: @codekaizer I think I'm confused and a bit too sleepy right now. I'll look at this later.

Comment: @codekaizer,  Only for simplicity,  no complex structures of decltype,  easier to understand, just this.

Comment: @codekaiser I think I was thinking about a different problem when I'm looking at this, and misunderstood a whole lot

Comment: @PasserBy, thank you for clarifying. only God knows what problem you were thinking. :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you only need non-empty packs (no-args call is already handled earlier). Should be straightforward:

```
template<typename... Tl> cons(Head h, Tl &&...tl)
    : cons_(std::move(h), Tail(std::forward<Tl>(tl)...)) {}
```

Btw, don't start identifiers with underscore.

---

Every answer here has one notable flaw: the structure constructed is an *improper* list: the last `cdr` in the sequence is not an empty list but rather a sequence. To construct proper lists, you'd have to end them properly. Something like:

```
struct Nil {};
inline bool operator==(Nil, Nil) { return true; }
inline bool operator!=(Nil, Nil) { return false; }
inline Nil make_cons() { return Nil{}; }

template<typename Car> inline auto make_cons(Car &&h) {
     return cons<std::remove_reference_t<Car>, Nil>{std::forward<Car>(h), Nil{}};
}

template<typename Car, typename Cadr, typename... Tail>
inline auto make_cons(Car &&first, Cadr &&second, Tail &&...rest) {
     return make_cons(std::forward<Car>(first)
                      , make_cons(std::forward<Cadr>(second), std::forward<Tail>(rest)...));
}
```

(For those unfamiliar with Lisp, Alexandrescu's type lists, that were probably one of the inspirations for C++11's variadic patterns, are basically the same.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid recursions in instantiation, you might do something like that:

```
template <typename T>
struct wrap_cons
{
    T&& t;
};


template <typename T, typename Head, typename Tail>
constexpr auto operator +(wrap_cons<T>&& w, cons<Head, Tail> c)
{
    return cons<T, cons<Head, Tail>>{std::forward<T>(w.t), std::move(c)};
}

template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto operator +(wrap_cons<T>&& w, wrap_cons<U>&& c)
{
    return cons<T, U>{std::forward<T>(w.t), std::forward<U>(c.t)};
}

template<typename... Args>
constexpr auto make_cons(Args... args)
{
    return (wrap_cons<Args>{std::forward<Args>(args)} + ...);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6af7d1a0cf53b374)

It might help to have bigger list.

Btw, [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) seems more appropriated that the old type-list.

Comment: I started with `std::tuple` actually but couldn't find a way to make it work with `prepend` function I am writing. Adding to the beginning of a list should be O(1). With tuple, it felt like I need to go through it and copy the contents.

Comment: tuple is a good way to handle product types but only if you are not going to extend it with new members I guess.

Comment: With `cons`, I don't see how you avoid the copy. you have `Tail` by value. If you use by reference/pointer, lifetime of previous `cons` is more complicated, and usage would be different too.

Comment: I pay for one copy to pass as argument but, it seems, with tuple I should copy again inside the constructor as well, to shift the values into a new tuple while prepending. With prepend, old `head` and `tail` should be merged into a new tuple before creating the new `cons`.

Comment: I meant that to prepend `char` to `std::tuple<int, std::string>`, you copy/move `char`, `int` and `string` to obtain `std::tuple<char, int, std::string>`. `char` and `cons<int, std::string>` are copied/moved to obtain `cons<char, cons<int, std::string>>`.

Comment: With references, tuple version is bigger indeed, `std::tuple<char&, int&, std::string&>` and `char&`/`std::tuple<int&, std::string&>` against `cons<char&, cons<int&, std::string&>&>` (reusing `cons<int&, std::string&>`), but in that case, you have to keep all intermediate objects.

Answer (score 1):

Every answer here has one serious flaw: the structure constructed is an *improper* list: the last `cdr` in the sequence is not an empty list but rather a sequence. To construct proper lists, you'd have to end them properly. Something like:

```
struct Nil {};
inline bool operator==(Nil, Nil) { return true; }
inline bool operator!=(Nil, Nil) { return false; }
inline Nil make_cons() { return Nil{}; }

template<typename Car> inline cons<std::remove_reference_t<Car>, Nil> make_cons(Car &&h) {
     return cons<Car, Nil>{std::forward<Car>(h), Nil{}};
}
template<typename Car, typename Cadr, typename... Tail> inline auto make_cons(Car &&first, Cadr &&second, Tail &&...rest) {
     return make_cons(std::forward<Car>(first)
                      , make_cons(std::forward<Cadr>(second), std::forward<Tail>(rest)...));
}
```